# How do I apply a function to rows in columns with names containing a partilcular stringin R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-processing

I have a dataframe with column names: X, time, "indoors_c" and "outdoors_c". Where time is >= 13, I want to replace the value of the rows in columns with names containing the string "_c" with 0. How do I do this without referring to the entire column name? I am using R studio

Comment: Please can you share a reproducible example of your data using ``dput()`` and edit the output into your question. Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Using functions from `tidyverse`, sse `across()` together with `contains()` to select the columns over which to apply the function. Then use `if_else` for the function, putting `0` values if column *time* is above/below some value.

Small reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)


data <- tibble(X=rnorm(20), time=1:20, indoors_c=rnorm(20),  outdoors_c=rnorm(20))

data %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("_c"), ~ if_else(time>=13, 0, .)))
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>          X  time indoors_c outdoors_c
#>      <dbl> <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 -1.67       1   -2.41      -1.44  
#>  2  1.00       2    0.113      0.701 
#>  3  0.386      3    0.0248    -0.425 
#>  4  0.266      4   -0.431     -0.0722
#>  5 -0.206      5    0.255     -1.34  
#>  6 -0.617      6    0.441      0.761 
#>  7  1.42       7    0.481     -0.892 
#>  8  0.207      8   -0.112     -0.906 
#>  9  1.42       9   -0.465     -0.527 
#> 10 -0.934     10   -2.21       2.95  
#> 11 -0.419     11   -0.639     -0.113 
#> 12  0.812     12   -0.180      0.440 
#> 13  0.331     13    0          0 
#> 14 -0.454     14    0          0     
#> 15 -0.0290    15    0          0     
#> 16  0.167     16    0          0     
#> 17 -0.150     17    0          0     
#> 18  0.922     18    0          0     
#> 19  1.77      19    0          0     
#> 20  1.62      20    0          0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('_C'), ~ case_when(time > 0 ~ 0, TRUE ~ .)))
```